# A complex matrix minus a diagonal matrix to be nilpotent...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a complex matrix, show that there exists a diagonal matrix $B$ and an integer $m$ such that $(A-B)^m=0$.

Comment: Hint: every complex matrix is [triangularizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Triangularisability), which is easier than Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 2):

More of a hint than a full answer: Every square complex matrix has a Jordan normal form. Take the Jordan normal form $J$ of $A$ and assume $A=PJP^{-1}$ and let $B = PCP^{-1}$ where $C$ is a diagonal matrix with the same numbers on its main diagonal as $J.$ Then $(A-B)^m = (P(J-C)P^{-1})^m = P(J-C)^mP^{-1}.$ Now show that $(J-C)^m= 0$ for some $m$ by using the fact that $J-C$ has all zeros on and below the main diagonal.

Comment: How is $B$ diagonal (which is what the question asked for)?

Comment: @copper.hat Year, I could not see that $B$ is diagonal also.

Comment: copper.hat: You are correct. For some reason I read the question as $B$ diagonalizble. My bad. I might think about this a bit more tomorrow.